# Is there any hook or event that is fired when user data is set/updated/deleted

Tags: 8, users

I am using the [`user.data`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21user%21src%21UserData.php/class/UserData/8.5.x) service to store additional data for users. I would like to trigger some custom functionality each time the `user.data` is changed. I can't find any hook or event that I could use. Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Can you confirm whether you are talking about the `user.data` service or updating user properties/fields?

Comment: Could you provide a sample use case of what exactly you are trying to do and when?

Comment: I'm talking about the user.data service.
One of the use cases is the following ones: I'm using search api and extended it to also index certain user.data. Now when the user.data changes I need to update the index. Everything works fine, except that I have to take cate by myself to update the index each time I update the user.data. It would be much easier if there would be ahook or event, so that I don't need to take care of updating the index throught my code. I'm using user.data quite a lot throught my code.

Answer (score 0):

[`hook_entity_presave`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21entity.api.php/function/hook_entity_presave/8.2.x) ([`hook_ENTITY_TYPE_presave`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21entity.api.php/function/hook_ENTITY_TYPE_presave/8.2.x))

> Act on an entity before it is created or updated.
>
> You can get the original entity object from $entity->original when it
>   is an update of the entity.

[`hook_entity_update`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21entity.api.php/function/hook_entity_update/8.2.x) ([`hook_ENTITY_TYPE_update`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21entity.api.php/function/hook_ENTITY_TYPE_update/8.2.x))

> Respond to updates to an entity.
>
> This hook runs once the entity storage has been updated. Note that
>   hook implementations may not alter the stored entity data. Get the
>   original entity object from $entity->original.

---

Here's a sample implemented by `system.module`:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_ENTITY_TYPE_presave() for user entities.
 */
function system_user_presave(UserInterface $account) {
  $config = \Drupal::config('system.date');
  if ($config->get('timezone.user.configurable') && !$account->getTimeZone() && !$config->get('timezone.user.default')) {
    $account->timezone = $config->get('timezone.default');
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't think UserData is an entity. So these won't work.

Comment: If the system module does this, its safe to say it works. It is using hook_user_presave, so it knows the argument being passed implements UserInterface. Try it.

Comment: [UserData](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21user%21src%21UserData.php/class/UserData/8.5.x) is a service that is more or less a a key/value store in the `users_data` table.

Comment: @mpdonadio - I'm getting confused. Did I misunderstand the question?

Comment: @leymannx Maybe?  My read was it was about the `user.data` service not updating user properties/fields.  Contact form is the only real place (?) it is used in core proper.

Comment: Yes, my question is about user.data. The entity hooks do not work in this case. I don't want to store the values in as fields.